Facing issues while building video compressor using ffmpeg library in .net framework 4.7.1
I was building Video Compressor using .net 4.2.1 framework and also I am using ffmpeg library for video compression. I am not getting an exact issue actually is ffmpeg library not working or request is not waiting for video to get compressed. By the way When I am pressing compress button to start video compression it is downloading a mp4 file having size of 0 kb. Please help if anyone is familar with this concept Thank you

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication16
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnCompress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (fileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                string inputFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
                string outputFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

                fileUpload.SaveAs(inputFilePath);

                CompressVideo(inputFilePath, outputFilePath, "640x480", "200k");

                Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"compressed_video.mp4\"");
                Response.TransmitFile(outputFilePath);
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("No file uploaded");
            }
        }
         static void CompressVideo(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath, string resolution , string bitrate  )
        {
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(inputFilePath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: Input file '{inputFilePath}' does not exist.");
                    return;
                }

                if (!IsValidVideoFile(inputFilePath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: Input file '{inputFilePath}' is not a valid video file.");
                    return;
                }

                string ffmpegPath = @"C:\Users\abhin\Downloads\ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl-shared\bin\ffmpeg.exe"; // Assuming ffmpeg is in PATH
                string args = $"-i \"{inputFilePath}\" -s {resolution} -b:v {bitrate} \"{outputFilePath}\" -y";

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = ffmpegPath,
                    Arguments = args,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true
                };

                using (Process process = new Process())
                {
                    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                    process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Data}");
                        }
                    };

                    process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Output: {e.Data}");
                        }
                    };

                    process.Start();
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    if (process.ExitCode != 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Error: ffmpeg process exited with code {process.ExitCode}");
                    }
                }

                if (!File.Exists(outputFilePath))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: Output file '{outputFilePath}' was not generated.");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Output file '{outputFilePath}' generated successfully.");
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(outputFilePath);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Output file size: {fileInfo.Length} bytes");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        static bool IsValidVideoFile(string filePath)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
            return extension.ToLower() == ".mp4" || extension.ToLower() == ".avi" || extension.ToLower() == ".mov";
        }
    }
}

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication16.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>Video Compression</h1>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCompress" runat="server" Text="Compress Video" OnClick="btnCompress_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>

I was building Video Compressor using .net 4.2.1 framework and also I am using ffmpeg library for video compression. I am not getting an exact issue actually is ffmpeg library not working or request is not waiting for video to get compressed. By the way When I am pressing compress button to start video compression it is downloading a mp4 file having size of 0 kb. Please help if anyone is familar with this concept
Thank you
